# Adobe CS 3 license

Tags: license

Can I still buy a legal Adobe CS3 license (from Adobe) eventhough CS4 has been released?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but probably not off the website. I tend to buy mine through third party vendors (corporate mandate) so I can't pass you a sales number. Typically though, big design shops migrate the whole infrastructure at the same time, so you end up buying new licenses long after "official" support is discontinued. We were buying CS2 licenses until last march.

Answer (score 1):

While [amazon still shows CS3 as a purchase option](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000NDIBYG), it might be cheaper to go ahead and [upgrade to CS4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001EUBSL0) if you're going to spending hundreds of dollars for a license.